# Hypotonic or Hypertonic solution and why?

Tags: homework

> A doctor needed to administer 5% albumin to a patient. Albumin is normally administered dissolved in 0.9% saline solution. Since the physician did not have any 5% albumin solution, he diluted 25% albumin with water and administered this to the patient. Describe what you think happened to the blood cells of the patient as a result?

So this is what I think:

If the doctor dilutes the 25% albumin, that will make the solution have a lower concentration of solute, creating a *hypotonic* solution. Therefore the water will move into the cells, causing them to swell, lyse or burst.

Is this correct?

Comment: Sure sounds correct to me.   p.s. Stupid doc's solution will be (0.9/5)% saline = 0.18% saline.  Way too low.

Answer (score 1):

Albumin wont form a true solution and wont affect the osmolarity greatly (colloid forming molecules like proteins can affect osmotic pressure to an extent. See [oncotic pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oncotic_pressure)).. and since there is no solute the solution would be hypotonic..

But what effect it will have on the blood cells depends on how much solution was injected.